# Using two past tense words in a sentence

Tags: past-tense, negation, grammar-myths

Somewhere I read that we should not use 2 past tense words in a sentence. Which among the following two statements are correct?

- > The files did not get processed by the system.
- > The files did not get process by the system.

Comment: Can you [edit] to add a link to where you read that?

Comment: @NathanTuggy He could have read it in a book.

Answer (score 1):

The first is correct.

To better understand the rules governing the use of past tense (or multiple words in past tense in the same sentence), see [this link](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/English/assume.html) (taken from the accepted answer on [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/60358/two-past-tenses-together-in-a-sentence-i-had-assumed-you-were-dead?rq=1)).

Also, note that in your example, the first sentence only contains one word in past tense: "did." Something can "get processed" in present tense - adding "-ed" to "process" makes it a verb, it doesn't assign a tense *per se*. For example: "The files are not being processed by the system."

Answer (score 0):

The first one is correct.
Processed means being processed, it's a passive form not past tense

Answer (score 0):

‘past tense words’ is not a usual way to talk about English verbs.

‘did’ and ‘processed’ are different verb *forms*. ‘did’ is always the past simple form of ‘do’, and ‘processed’ is, *in this sentence*, the past participle form of ‘process’.

Also, in this sentence, ‘did’ and ‘processed’ are performing different *functions*. ‘did’ is the auxiliary verb needed to form a past simple negative statement, and is always followed by a base form verb - here ‘get’. ‘get processed’ is a kind of passive voice, which is usually formed with ‘be + past participle’ (‘the files are processed by the system’ (*not* ‘are process’)), but can, more informally, be formed with ‘get + past participle’ (‘the files get processed by the system’ (*not* ‘get process’)). (The other way of checking that ‘processed’ is a past participle is to substitute an irregular verb: ‘the files are/get *written* by the system’.)

> ‘we should not use 2 past tense words in a sentence’.

It is perfectly allowable (in fact it is required) to use a past simple verb form and a past participle verb form in past perfect and/or past passive tenses. In fact it is possible to create a *past perfect passive* sentence like ‘the files had (past simple) been (be-past participle) processed (main verb-past participle)’.

*But*, it is *probably* * true that we *can’t* (not just ‘should not’) use two past simple verb forms in the same function of a verb string: *‘the system processed printed the files’. (But we can join them with ‘and’: ‘the system processed and printed the files’.)

*I don’t want to flatly state that ‘we can’t’ in case there are any exceptions (for example, idioms or formulaic expressions). If there *are* any exceptions, I can’t immediately think of them.

Answer (score 0):

Past fences.      Sub +2nd form +objects