# "Had thought" vs "had assumed."

Tags: word-choice

[had assumed](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/60358/two-past-tenses-together-in-a-sentence-i-had-assumed-you-were-dead)

Just like some movie scenario, one had thought another dead. When they met, one said,

> I had thought your were dead.

Or

> I had assumed you were dead.

Which is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think both are fine given different contexts.

If this is casual conversation, I would use: 
'I thought you were dead.' Because if someone just found out that someone is alive that they thought was dead, I don't know they would care about using 'had'.

Note: in American English, a school of thought is to not use assume. The reason is, by making the assumption the person failed to verify an outcome.

'I had assumed you were dead' could mean, I thought you were dead because I was too lazy to verify if it was false.

While,

'I had thought you were dead' could mean, I thought you were dead because I verified all available evidence and that was the best conclusion.

We have a silly saying for assumptions: 
Assuming makes an 'ass' out of 'u' and 'me'. Get it? Ass-u-me?

However, if the person really did not verify the outcome, they had assumed and that would be correct.

Anyway, hope that helps.